# Android lib-project generated from command line misconfigured by default

Tags: android, command-line, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools, android-build

I need to generate Android library projects and build them from the command line. I'm running into an issue where they are misconfigured by default when they are generated and I'm not sure how to fix it other then manually editing the misconfigured files.

I run the android command from the commandline like this:

```
 android create lib-project -n Test -t 2 -k net.marklar.test -g -v 1.1.3 -p .
```

This causes a project to be generated that declares its dependency on gradle 1.12 in test/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties, even though the Android gradle plugin requires 2.1+ to work:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip
```

Once I replace the line in gradle-wrapper.properties I still have an issue where the build.gradle file has the following line:

```
runProguard false
```

runProguard has been renamed to minifyEnabled in plugins version 1.0.0+. Replacing this line with minifyEnabled fixes the build.

Does anyone know what I have setup incorrectly that could cause the projects to be generated with old/deprecated configuration?

Comment: Yes, this happens to me each time. I think it is simply because they have not updated the templates used.

Comment: Thanks, good to know its not just me